# How to set Firebase database rules for group messaging app

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have set Firebase database rules for a group messaging app. But now even when an authenticated user tries to send a message it doesn't get displayed.

I am working on a group messaging app. The code can be found at the following [link](https://github.com/RazaCodeRepo/Plan). When creating the app I was using default rules for the Firebase database. But now I am trying set rules so that all the uid available in the members node can see or send messages to that particular group. Below are the latest set of rules that I have created. Below is my detailed database structure after a plan is created. Please note that I am making use of Firebase Phone Authentication. For this reason I am creating a users node which keeps track of uid against every registered number. When a user selects members to be added to the group I check those numbers against their respective uid's and then add those uid's in the member's node.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "plan":{
      "$planID":{
        "messages":{
          ".read":"data.parent().child('members').child(auth.uid).exists()",
          ".write":"data.parent().child('members').child(auth.uid).exists()"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Data Structure]

I expected authenticated users who have been added to the members node to be able to read and send messages but instead even the registered users themselves cannot create a new group or read the messages after the above rules have been published.

Comment: Please include the code you are using to test this and your database structure as text.

Comment: @AndréKool I have added a link to the github repository of the project

Answer (score 0):

1. When defining every sub-node as Integers, starting from zero (as you did in `members`), Firebase automatically interprets the whole node as it if was an [Array of Objects](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html), and in such case you cannot treat them as if they were sub-nodes at all (by calling `child(auth.uid)`).

   Quote from the link:

   > In particular, if all of the keys are integers, and more than half of the keys between 0 and the maximum key in the object have non-empty values, then Firebase will render it as an array. This latter part is important to keep in mind.

   Since this is the case in your Data Structure, all of `members`' sub-nodes are no longer considered nodes. They are array items, and therefore are not `children` of `members`.
2. Even if it weren't the case, and they were all sub-nodes - you seem to call `child(auth.uid)` as if `auth.uid` was an Integer: Your "sub-nodes" are all **Integers**, while `auth.uid` is defined **String**.